# How should the model communicate?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I am designing a JavaScript application that involves the editing of text based files, (aka code editor). Currently, I am working on the file explorer area of the application. I have divided it up into three MVC parts.

1. The view, which manages the DOM Stricture (via jQuery primarily) and publishes user interactions to my applications mediator. (Eg. The user clicks "Add File", the view will ask for a name, then trigger the "files.new" event with the new name.)
2. The controller. The controller will be receiving most of the events triggered by the view. From what I understand, the controller should be responsible for updating the model. If, for example, the view triggers the "files.nameChanged" event with the new name, the controller will handle that event by updating the model.
3. The model. Currently the model is limited to just the raw data. There are no events or any kind of api. Which leads me into my question:

How should the model communicate? I've considered exposing an API such as `model.updateRecord()`. But if I do that how can the view communicate which record should be updated? If the user changes the name of a file for example, how will the controller know which file was changed, and how will it communicate that to the model?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a point of Models like so many people do - **A model is an abstraction concept** There are no models in MVC, but services, so you need some kind of DataMapper

Comment: @DaveJust Sounds fine to me, but the question still stands as to how the... "data module?" should communicate with the rest of the application, or more specifically, the view module.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Dave Just's comment, model is a layer. The model layer consists of services, domain objects and data mappers. See the chart below. The registry is not part of the model layer, it is something I added before finishing my framework, it isn't in the right spot or have an accurate description in the diagram, but I'm not sure it applies to javascript frameworks anyways.

image link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ENyB.jpg